# Given a list of numbers, check if there exists numbers that add to 100. List all those numbers as a list of lists

Tags: python, list, brute-force

```
Input : L=[1,50,16,34,8,42,99]

Output : [[50,8,42],[16,34,50],[99,1],[16,34,42,8]]
```

Create a function `check_sum_100(L)`

I am able to find the sum of elements that add up to 100 when the elements form sub-array. But I am not able to find list of elements like `[99,1]`.

Here is what I tried to implement:

```
def check_sum_100(L):
    out=[]
    for i in range(0, len(L)):             
        for j in range(i, len(L)): 
            sum = 0 
            temp = []                       
            for k in range (i, j+1):
                sum = sum + L[k]            
                temp.append(L[k])
            if sum == 100:
                out.append(temp)
    return out


L = [1,50,16,34,8,42,99]

o = check_sum_100(L)

print(o)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `itertools.combinations` to get sublists of varying length and check for the sum:

```
import itertools

def check_sum_100(L):
    output = list()
    for l in range(len(L)+1):
        for sublist in itertools.combinations(L, l):
            if sum(sublist)==100:
                output.append(sublist)         
    return output

>>> check_sum([1,50,16,34,8,42,99])
[(1, 99), (50, 16, 34), (50, 8, 42), (16, 34, 8, 42)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion for this sort of problem:

```py
def check_sum_100(L):
    # inner function looks for a specific sum target and generates combinations
    def check_sum(L,target):
        for i,v in enumerate(L):
            if v == target:       # base condition, a number in L is the target
                yield [v]
            else:
                # check the sublist after this number for sums that equal the remainder
                for o in check_sum(L[i + 1:], target - v):
                    yield [v] + o
    return list(check_sum(L, 100))

L = [1,50,16,34,8,42,99]
print(check_sum_100(L))
```

Output:

```
[[1, 99], [50, 16, 34], [50, 8, 42], [16, 34, 8, 42]]
```

Comment: I had a similar approach in mind, however this should still test all combinations right? I was also wondering about another approach using a sorted input. Start from an end, add the combinations from the other end until you reach a match or skip the rest if above/below target (depending on which side you add). No time to code it unfortunately :p

Comment: @mozway Yes, all combinations.  It does produce duplicates if there are duplicate numbers, e.g. `L = [25,75,25]` produces `[[25,75],[75,25]]` (1st/2nd, 2nd/3rd) but using tuples, `return list(set(check_sum(L, 100))` and sorting the input would fix that if desired.  OP didn't have duplicates.